# ContextPath and autocompletion with subpackages

Tags: packages, contexts, autocomplete

I'm developing a larger package which includes several subpackages. My problem is, that I can't introduce the symbols in the subpackages to the autocompletion by loading the main package, but by calling a subpackage.

Let's explain this with an example: I have a main package, called `main` which loads the subpackages `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub3`. The directory should look like

```
main
├── Kernel
│   └── init.m
├── main.m
├── sub1.m
├── sub2.m
└── sub3.m
```

The package `main` loads all three subpackages in its `BeginPackage` statement, while the package `sub1` loads `sub2` and `sub3`. The respective `init.m` looks like:

```
Get["main`sub3`"]
Get["main`sub2`"]
Get["main`sub1`"]
Get["main`main`"]
```

The big problem I have is, that by calling

```
Needs["main`"]
```

I can see all symbols in `main`, but not those in the subpackages (though, they are usable).

By calling

```
Needs["main`sub1`"]
```

I can see all symbols in the subpackages without any problems but can't load `main` anymore, because then some definitions are redone, which leads to error messages about protected symbols. The most interesting thing is, that the `$ContextPath` includes the subpackages in both cases.

Is there a nice possibility to get the symbols of the subpackages into the autocompletion?

---

*Update*: By prepending the path of a subpackage to the `$ContextPath`, I can load the corresponding symbols of that package into the autocompletion.

```
$ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath, "main`sub1`"]
```

Unfortunately, this is not very nice and yields duplicates in the `$ContextPath`.

Is there a better, automatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give additional information, what I found, at least in Mathematica version 9, is that one must load the subpackages after the main package in order to have autocompletion for the subpackages symbols. When we do this the subpackages appear before the main package in the `$ContextPath`, so when you have a `init.m` like this:

```
Get["main`main`"]
Get["main`sub1`"]
Get["main`sub2`"]
Get["main`sub3`"]
```

you have `` $ContextPath = {main`sub3`, main`sub2`, main`sub1`, main`main`, ...} ``, and voilà, we have autocompletion.

I don't understand why Mathematica "shadows" the subpackage symbols when they appear after the main package in the `$ContextPath`, but this is the solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have deal with Mathematica [application](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/applications.html).

I know 2 way for solv this problem

1) Add path to your application in variable $Path. And then load with `Get`

```
AppendTo[$Path,"C:\\path\\to\\your\\application"];
<<main`
```

This code try to find init.m in your application and evaluate it.

2) Save your application in directory `$UserBaseDirectory <> "\\Autoload"` and it will load with mathematica start (withe the way described in previous way).